# comparar valor actual con anterior e imprimir, while php

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, while

Tengo una consulta a la bd, la cual me trae registros, dichos registros son una serie de numeros de telefono los cuales
pertecen a un id, esto es resultado de un proceso de limpieza de estos telefonos.
Los diferentes telefonos pueden pertenecer a un mismo id (cliente), cuando esa condicion se cumpla, deberia agrupar ese telefono en la fila donde se encontro ese id

ejemplo

alvaro
id = 1
telefono 22312

alvaro id = 1
telefono 123213

id---    tlf

1   --  22312

1  --   123213

deberia quedar

id ------  tlf   ------   tlf1

1 ----   22312  --   123213

Hasta ahora he logrado agruparlas gracias al aporte de un miembro de stackoverFlorw.

Ahora tendria que terminar de mostrar la tabla para que no se me corte al cumplir cierta condicion, estoy trabajando con datatables de jquery

el codigo

```
      $telefonosLimpiarValidados = mostrarTelefonosFinal($cartera, $fecha, 
       $empresa, $connection); ?>

                 <div class="table-responsive" id="data-tabla-html">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" 
                     cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="example">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id_local</th>
                                <th>documento</th>
                                <th>telefono</th>
                                <th>telefono1</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

              <?php if (is_object($telefonosLimpiarValidados)) {

               if (isset($_SESSION["accionTabla"]) && 
                $_SESSION["accionTabla"] === 'final') {

                          $lastUser = "";
                          $lastCell = "";
                          while ($recorroTelefonos = 
              mysqli_fetch_assoc($telefonosLimpiarValidados)) {
              $largo = strlen($recorroTelefonos["telefono"]);

             if ($largo === 10 ||  $largo === 12) {
             if ($recorroTelefonos["sin_15"] !== '0') {

            $user = $recorroTelefonos["id_local"];
             if ($user != $lastUser) { ?>
                <tr>
                 <!-- Muestro datos -->
               <td> <?php echo $recorroTelefonos["id_local"]; ?></td>
              <td> <?php echo $recorroTelefonos["documento"]; ?></td>
              <td> <?php echo $recorroTelefonos["telefono"]; ?></td>
                                                       
                                                    
          <?php } else { 
                                                            
           $cell = $recorroTelefonos["telefono"];
          if ($cell != $lastCell) { ?>
                                                        
        <td> <?php echo $recorroTelefonos["telefono"]; ?></td>
         <?php } else { 
                     //nada                                      
                }
                    ?>
               </tr>
            <?php  }
            $lastUser = $user;
          $lastCell = isset($cell) ? $cell : '';                                                 
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            } 
                     </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

el codigo que llevo hasta ahora es el siguiente

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Comment: lo que quieres es comparar si en la tabla telefenos existen varios registros telefonicos por el mismo usuario cierto? y luego hacer un echo tipo telefono 1 -> 23232 telefno 2 -> 231235

Comment: si. exactamente

Comment: Hola, cualquier tipo de código que desees mostrar, procura que sea en texto, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function cerrarFila(int $cantidadTelefonos)
{
    while ($cantidadTelefonos < 9) {
        echo "<td></td>";
        $cantidadTelefonos++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

$ultimoUsuario = "";
$ultimoTelefono = "";
$cantidadTelefonos = 9;

while ($recorroTelefonos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($telefonosLimpiarValidados)) {
    $usuario = $recorroTelefonos["id_local"];
    $telefono = $recorroTelefonos["telefono"];

    $largo = strlen($telefono);
    if ($largo != 10 && $largo != 12) continue;
    if ($recorroTelefonos["sin_15"] === '0') continue;

    if ($usuario != $ultimoUsuario) {
        if ($cantidadTelefonos < 9) cerrarFila($cantidadTelefonos);
        echo "<tr>
        <td>$usuario</td>
        <td>{$recorroTelefonos['documento']}</td>
        <td>$telefono</td> ";
        $cantidadTelefonos = 1;
    } else {
        if ($telefono != $ultimoTelefono) {
            echo "<td>$telefono</td>";
            $cantidadTelefonos++;
        }
    }

    $ultimoUsuario = $usuario;
    $ultimoTelefono = $telefono;
}
cerrarFila($cantidadTelefonos);
```

Comment: y si no son siempre son consecutivos? Otra opcion seria hacerle un select from por cada iteracion.?

Comment: Consultar la base de datos en cada iteración es muy mala idea porque aumentas el tiempo de respuesta innecesariamente. Si los registros de un mismo usario no son consecutivos, podes hacerle un `order by documento` a tu consulta para poder seguir usando esta solucion o sino tendrías que recorrer el bucle 2 veces: la primera para agrupar los datos y la segunda para mostrarlos. Si este es tu caso puedo editar la respuesta

Comment: bro me esta sirviendo tu respuesta. Lo unico que la tabla se me corta pero porque me falta una condicion para que se muestre la fila vacia cuando no cumpla la condicion

Comment: edita tu pregunta con el codigo actualizado

Comment: pero en texto, no como captura

Comment: falta código. completalo hasta el cierre del while

Comment: Completado el codigo.

Comment: hay algo mal.. no puedo ejecutarlo

Comment: ahi lo complete mas. Si agrego todo el scrip se haria muy largo el documento porque lo de mas que tengo es puro manejo de errores con las sesiones

Comment: respondida y resuelta por Sinner of the System.